# Why does ctime clock() give different times when called twice by same program for same operation?

Tags: c++, c

I am calling clock() from the same code multiple times to compute time taken by different sets of operations. I noticed that it takes more time for the first set of operations even if these steps are supposedly faster than later sets of operations. So I tested with same set of operations, as shown in the example code given below. The following example returns 0.001 ms for set 1 and ~ 0 ms for set 2, although set 1 and set 2 are same operations. Any explanation for this behaviour?

Example code:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <ctime>
  3 
  4 using namespace std;
  5 
  6 int main()
  7 {
  8     int x = 1000000;
  9 
 10     //Set 1:
 11     clock_t t0 = clock();
 12     int y = x * x;
 13     y *= x;
 14     t0 = clock() - t0;
 15     
 16     //Set 2:
 17     clock_t t1 = clock();
 18     int z = x * x;
 19     z *= x;
 20     t1 = clock() - t1;
 21     
 22     cout << "Set1 : " << (double)t0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << " ms." << endl;
 23     cout << "Set2 : " << (double)t1/CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << " ms." << endl;
 24     
 25     return 0;
 26 }
```

Comment: clock() is nowhere near accurate enough to measure such fast operations reliably.

Comment: If you average out the time for several thousand operations I wager they'd be equal.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. Replace the fast operations in the example with some longer operation, e.g., quick sort of say 1 million numbers. Call it two times. Time taken for first call is longer!

Comment: @SANDEEPPALAKKAL "Replace ... with some longer operation. Call it two times. Time taken for first call is longer!". Experiment some more. E.g. use `-O0` optimisations (you are doing nothing with your `y` and `z`, optimized code will simply discard the computation entrely as irrelevant); call it 3-4-5 times; put in a `current_thread::sleep` between the two consecutive executions; make sure it's not a fluke. Use high precision timers on your platform

Comment: There's nothing to keep the compiler from moving the arithmetic across the calls to `clock()`, performing common subexpression elimination to omit the second computation, or (most likely) constant-folding the whole thing so that there's no code at all between the calls to `clock()` and the code at the end just prints constants.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the explanation in the first sentence of the [clock(3) manual](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/clock.3.html) page:

> The clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used
>   by the program.

Special emphasis on the "***approximation***" part.

It also doesn't help things that a modern CPU can easily execute more than a few multiplication instructions, like the ones in your code, all in the space of a single clock tick. Throw into the mix CPU caches, pipelining, and preemptive multitasking, and this kind of a measurement is pretty much meaningless.